# Loading Models From In Libraries In Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my systems libraries folder I have a custom **user library** file. I put it in there because I have multiple codeigniter installs.

I can not seem to call my admin directories user model using fcpath.

```
$this->CI->load->model(dirname(FCPATH) . '/admin/application/modules/backend/models/user/user_model.php');
```

Any suggestions.

Comment: Are you getting the CI instance before using it? `$this->CI = &get_instance();`

Comment: and are you sure `dirname(FCPATH) . '/admin/application/modules/backend/models/user/user_model.php'` returns what it should? What error are you getting?

Comment: `FCPATH` is a directory

Answer (score 0):

Just been more looking around Google and able to load it now all working now I hope. Just going to test it.

```
$file = dirname(FCPATH) . '/admin/application/modules/backend/models/user/user_model.php';
$file = dirname(FCPATH) . '/install/application/modules/setup/models/install_model.php'; // Only For Install Once

if(file_exists($file)) {
return true;
} else {
echo "Can't find file located in: " . $file;
}
```